# Pass csv of ints to Stored proc and use for IN()

Tags: sql-server

I want to pass a csv of int

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

to a stored procedure so that I can use the passed-in values in an IN() so that

```
IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: So the CSV is always going to have 1 row in it of values?

Comment: you can use dynamic sql, or a split function as pointed out in the flagged answer.  When splitting, you can either join onto the table that your split values are stored, or `in (select value from splitValues)`

Comment: You might also take a look here. The flagged answer is using a recursive cte which works well enough but it pretty inefficient. Here are some better options. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: What you really want to do is to pass in a Table-Valued Parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you simply mean to use a dynamic parameter for your SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[takeMeAndMySeeEzzBee]
    @csv VARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(255)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT THIS_AND_THAT FROM HERE WHERE YOU_ARE IN(' + @csv + ')'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END;
GO
-- I will runawayyyy
EXEC [dbo].[takeMeAndMySeeEzzBee] @csv='1,2,3,4'
```

^ is an example of how dynamic SQL can work.

Now if you mean to pull data from a `.csv` file, let us know; my answer will change.

Comment: Nice! Only one issue may occur - it needs special rights to execute 'sp_executesql', but maybe this is not an issue to an OP :) here is my up

Comment: @RDJ I want to pass .csv to SP and read data, so can you please give solution for that also

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcName
    @csv nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @xml xml

    SELECT @xml = CAST('<a>' + REPLACE(@csv,',','</a><a>') +'</a>' as xml)

    SELECT what_you_need
    FROM some_table s
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT t.v.value('.','int') as something
        FROM @xml.nodes('/a') as t(v)
        ) as p
        ON p.something = s.something
END
```

Or:

```
SELECT what_you_need
FROM some_table s
WHERE s.something IN (
    SELECT t.v.value('.','int') as something
    FROM @xml.nodes('/a') as t(v)
    )
```