# How to pass CSV to a stored procedure and use it in WHERE IN?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a stored procedure, I want to pass a CSV to it and use this csv in a `WHERE IN` clause.

I have done it by passing XML to the stored procedure like this:

```
WHERE MyColumn IN (SELECT AOS.s.value('(./text())[1]', 'bigint')  
                   FROM (VALUES(@XML))V(X)  
                   CROSS APPLY  
                       V.X.nodes('/ArrayOfLong/long') AOS(s))
```

Result-wise, this stored procedure works fine, but it's slow. I want to improve the performance. When I run this stored procedure and get the execution plan, I get a warning.

I have also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37663010/6527049) answer, but I cannot use this solution due to permission issues, as mentioned in the comments.

I am looking for a simple clean and optimized solution.

Parameters should be like this `'1,2,3,4,5,6,7'` and it will be used like this `WHERE IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`

[image]

[image]

**Edit**:

[image]

Comment: I *assume*, therefore, you are on SQL Server 2014-?

Comment: @Larnu I have just added the info

Comment: That's a screenshot of the version of SSMS (which is oddly 18.4, why haven't you updated in almost 3 years?); that doesn't tell me what version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: @Larnu how to know that?

Comment: `PRINT @@VERSION`.

Comment: @Larnu Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU16-GDR) (KB5014353) - 15.0.4236.7 (X64) 
 May 29 2022 15:55:47 
 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Why not use `STRING_SPLIT` and `JOIN` to that?

Comment: I'm confused: do you have a CSV or XML? If you are creating XML from the CSV can you show how you do that? You could use a Table Valued Parameter, if you give it an index that is likely to be the fastest option.

Comment: It says Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'. when I run this 'SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', ' ');' @Larnu

Comment: @Charlieface I have CSV in the code, I have converted it to XML to pass to the SP. Will it solve the issue which I am facing mentioned  in the above screenshot

Comment: What compatibility level is your database in, @viveknuna  (and why is it 120 or lower)?

Comment: @Larnu its 120.

Comment: Is there a reason it's 120 and not 150?

Comment: @Larnu I don't think we can change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should use a Table Valued Parameter for this.**

First, create a table type. I usually keep a few standard ones. In this case you probably want a primary key, which gets you a free index.

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.IdList AS TABLE (Id int PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then you use it in your procedure like this

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.YourProc
    @ids dbo.IdList READONLY
AS

SELECT s.Something
FROM Somewhere s
WHERE s.MyColumn IN (
    SELECT i.Id FROM @id i
);
```

You call it like this from T-SQL

```sql
DECLARE @tmp dbo.IdList;
INSERT @tmp (Id) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3);

EXEC YourProc @ids = @tmp;
```

In client applications, there is normally special handling for TVPs. Use those rather than injecting `INSERT` statements into your query.

You may also need to add permissions for non-admin users

```sql
GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE::dbo.IntList to db_datareader;
```

Comment: Why do we need to add permission?

Comment: @Do you know how to pass this parameter from C# code to this SP?

Comment: You need to add permissions because by default you don't get `EXECUTE` on any table types. Yes, there are many tutorials, see here for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/66067309/14868997

Answer (score 0):

Load the CSV into a table using SSIS and then just join your original table to the newly loaded table with the CSV data.